# Appropriate method for transition function in gdistance

Tags: r, gis

The following code is an example for the transition function from the pdf manual for gdistance:

```
library(raster)
library(gdistance)

r <- raster(nrows=6, ncols=7, xmn=0, xmx=7, ymn=0, ymx=6, crs="+proj=utm +units=m")
r[] <- c(2, 2, 1, 1, 5, 5, 5,
         2, 2, 8, 8, 5, 2, 1,
         7, 1, 1, 8, 2, 2, 2,
         8, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 5,
         8, 8, 1, 1, 5, 3, 9,
         8, 1, 1, 2, 5, 3, 9)
T <- transition(r, function(x) 1/mean(x), 8)
# 1/mean: reciprocal to get permeability
T <- geoCorrection(T)
c1 <- c(5.5,1.5)
c2 <- c(1.5,5.5)
#make a SpatialLines object for visualization
sPath1 <- shortestPath(T, c1, c2, output="SpatialLines")
plot(r)
lines(sPath1)
#make a TransitionLayer for further calculations
sPath2 <- shortestPath(T, c1, c2)
plot(raster(sPath2))
```

My specific interest is in this line:

```
T <- transition(r, function(x) 1/mean(x), 8)
```

Because I've come across numerous examples of people doing the following:

```
T <- transition(1/r, mean, 8)
```

As far as I can tell, this is the difference between `1/mean(x)` and `mean(1/x)`, which are not equivalent.

To verify this, I ran both versions of the transition function using the above code from the gdistance manual, and got these two very different plots:
[image]
[image]

And using `costDistance(T, c1, c2)` I got a distance of 21.1 for the first, and 13.6 for the second.

Clearly, these are very different results. So, my question is, what is the correct method for creating a TransitionLayer object from a cost matrix/layer/raster?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is indeed an important difference. Take a look at the Wikipedia article on the *harmonic mean* for more info.

In the example, the values in the input raster are costs. So the correct way is to take the arithmetic mean of the cost first and then take the reciprocal of that to get the conductance. The traveller experiences half of the cost of the origin cell and half of the cost of the destination cell, (cost1 + cost2)/2.

So 1/mean(x) is correct for this case.

If the input raster has conductance values, the other function is correct: mean(1/x).

Comment: My understanding is that conductance and cost (resistance) are inversely related (G = 1/R). So in the first example, they are using a cost layer, whereas the second is using the corresponding conductance layer (1/r). Given that's it's the same layer, just different representations, shouldn't they both eventually produce the same least-cost path? Should  `T <- transition(1/r, mean, 8)` actually be `T <- transition(1/r, function(x) 1/mean(1/x), 8)`, which does give the same result?

Comment: They do give the same result, if you then take harmonic means on the conductance layer, and arithmetic means on the resistance layer. T <- transition(1/r, function(x) 1/mean(1/x), 8) is equivalent to taking the harmonic mean.

Comment: So, in other words "just different representations" does not mean that you can do the same operations and then just take the reciprocal at the end, and expect the result to be the same. This is the same mistake as averaging speed with the arithmetic mean, which is incorrect (see Wikipedia article on harmonic mean under "In physics").