# R: gdistance: transition-stack summary calculation-time error

Tags: r, matrix

i have a Digital Elevaiton model (DEM) with ~1million cells, from which i generate a transition matrix using Toblers Hiking function with 8 neigbors, as described in [van Etten 2017](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gdistance/vignettes/gdistance1.pdf).

```
class       : TransitionLayer 
dimensions  : 1395, 778, 1085310  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution  : 299.8762, 300.1004  (x, y)
extent      : 4192608, 4425912, 2775384, 3194024  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=merc +lon_0=45 +k=1 +x_0=5000000 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 
+units=m +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
values      : conductance 
matrix class: dgCMatrix
```

I have a second Raster describing the Landuse with factors relating to travel speed (grassland=1, desert=2, rocks=5, rivers=20, sea=99). From this, i calculate a transition matrix using the mean values.

```
tr_LU<-transition(LU_agg, mean, 8, symm=F)
```

LU_transition-matrix:

```
class       : TransitionLayer 
dimensions  : 1395, 778, 1085310  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution  : 299.8762, 300.1004  (x, y)
extent      : 4192608, 4425912, 2775384, 3194024  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=merc +lon_0=45 +k=1 +x_0=5000000 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 
+units=m +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
values      : conductance 
matrix class: dsCMatrix
```

I want to bring both transition layers together so i stack them and sum them up by calculating the product.

```
st<-stack(tr_LU,conductance)
trProd<-prod(st)
```

calculations took over 30h before i aborted them, which, to me, seems unlikely to be realistic, considering its only 8million simple multiplications (both rasters ~1million cells; transition calculated with 8 neighbors ->8million values). No errors were given, just 30h of constant 25% CPU usage.

Could this calculation time be realistic or is it some kind of error?

If it is realistic which other ways do i have to correlate both Rasters? I considered transforming the DEM-transition-matrix to a accumulated-cost-surface-raster and multiplying its cell values with the cell values from the LandUse-raster. But how do i convert the result back to a transition matrix, since gdistance needs one?

The DEM- and the LU-raster, as well as the complete script can be accessed [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1w3hFz_kApVWJ3bkhrb-U-4fatm-dqgvV)

Comment: Multiplying an accumulated cost surface does not make much sense, I think. To convert your land use specific values into conductance values, you should not take the arithmetic mean, but the harmonic one. See here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47739676/appropriate-method-for-transition-function-in-gdistance

Comment: thats a good hint, thank you, i will implement that

Answer (score 0):

Try with a smaller example first. These functions are not very optimized because they rely on the Matrix and igraph packages. To make the calculation doable, you can aggregate the data first. Usually aggregation does not change the final results too much in distance calculations.

The following toy example works.

```
library(gdistance)

r <- raster(nrows=6, ncols=7, xmn=0, xmx=7, ymn=0, ymx=6, crs="+proj=utm +units=m")

r[] <- c(2, 2, 1, 1, 5, 5, 5,
         2, 2, 8, 8, 5, 2, 1,
         7, 1, 1, 8, 2, 2, 2,
         8, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 5,
         8, 8, 1, 1, 5, 3, 9,
         8, 1, 1, 2, 5, 3, 9)

Tr <- transition(r, function(x) 1/mean(x), 8)

TrProd <- Tr * Tr
```

Or

```
s <- stack(Tr, Tr)
p <- prod(s)
```

Comment: yes aggregating the raster is of course always a possibility but i tried to avoid that since i already aggregated them from 30m DEM to 300m DEM in order to be able to generate transition matrices

Answer (score 0):

i solved the problem by using artithmetic functions instead of the prod() function. So instead of

```
s <- stack(Tr, Tr)
p <- prod(s)
```

i used

```
tr_accumulated<-tr_DEM*tr_LU
```

the arithmetic functions were a little bit more responsive too: for every other function (like +,-,/) it threw the error "operation too large". Only the * function seemed to work, so i inversed the values of the tr_LU beforehand and finally got the result i wanted.

Obviously with this setup i was working at the limits of R capabilities/system ressources, still i dont understand the behaviour of the the prod() function. With the working code it took ~1min, with the prod() function over 30h. Shouldnt the prod()-function finish at some point or interrupt and throw an error message?